# Non thread/cpu dependent workers? - Python

Tags: multithreading, pool, worker

I'm looking to run a pseudo "multithreading" process which is independent of core/thread count. Is there a similar process to this where it's not cpu/thread based?

```
with Pool(int(Multithread_Count)) as p:
        #p.map(Cas_off, Input_Casoff) #OCT10
        #print(p.map(Cas_off, Input_Casoff))
        print(p.starmap(Cas_off, zipped))
```

So i can create 64x instances of a "worker" without being limited on thread count?

For reference this is part of a larger code which takes 6000 files and processes them in intervals of 24, due to 24 threads and each thread being a worker.
It takes about 4 hours using multithreading....

Best regards,
James

Comment: Threads are always independent of core count; e.g. the typical modern CPU has 4-8 cores but has hundreds or thousands of threads running on it most of the time.  So your program can spawn as many threads as it likes (up to some limit, anyway, probably in the hundreds or thousands), although whether spawning more threads will speed things up or not is another question.

Comment: Note also that Python's multithreading efficiency is seriously limited by the presence of the GIL ( https://realpython.com/python-gil/ ), which causes Python threads to execute one-at-a-time to a large extent, even on multi-core machines.

Comment: Check [greenlets](https://greenlet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and similar libraries.